# Jenkins pipeline unable to find Java when same script used with another project is working fine

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am getting following error

```
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module! :dependency
[INFO] Compiling 7 source files with javac [debug target 1.8] to target/classes
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  36.513 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2023-11-16T05:23:59Z
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.11.0:compile (default-compile) on project project-name: Fatal error compiling: tools.jar not found: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-amazon-corretto/../lib/tools.jar -> [Help 1]
```

I checked the java version in the pipeline and it shows correctly as below

```
[Pipeline] sh
+ java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_392"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Corretto-8.392.08.1 (build 1.8.0_392-b08)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Corretto-8.392.08.1 (build 25.392-b08, mixed mode)
[Pipeline] sh
+ javac -version
javac 1.8.0_392
```

What might be the issue?

Comment: That `../lib/tools.jar` looks odd, because that would resolve the file to `/usr/lib/jvm/lib/tools.jar`. Perhaps something's wrong with the Java installation. Is it installed manually, or through Jenkins itself?

Comment: It is done through a build slave which is based on amazon corretto jdk8 image

Comment: And that's installed using Jenkins tool management? Can you make sure that the folders are setup correctly there?